# How to avoid repeating base class constructor parameters in derived class in TypeScript, Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
@Injectable()
export class APIService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

}


@Injectable()
export class CourseAPIService extends APIService{

  constructor(private http2: Http){
    super(http2);
  }
}
```

I have baseclass as APIService having Http as constructor parameter unfortunately I have to pass it again in child class CourseAPIService.
Please help me if any soln ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the constructor completely from `CourseAPIService` if you are not using the `private http2` property in `CourseAPIService` .

If you do want to use the `Http` service in `CourseAPIService`, you can mark the `http` property as `protected` in `APIService` and share it with `CourseAPIService`.

```
@Injectable()
export class APIService {
  constructor(protected http: Http) {
  }
}
```

However if you define a constructor for `CourseAPIService` you must call its base class constructor with `super` passing necessary arguments.

Comment: Thanks, but what if we want to have constructor in `CourseAPIService` but still we want to prevent passing arguments of the base component (in this case `http`)?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the answer is No. You need call super() from derived class. So, if your base class has dependencies, your derived class must inject same dependencies and pass to super() method.